# Link to iPhone map App from HTML page

Tags: iphone, mobile, map-directions

Is there a way to link to directions in the iPhone map app from a html page?

We're placing an add in an iPhone app which will link to a mobile page on our website - we'd like to add a directions link, thus far google searches have been unrevealing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Here is a javascript function that creates the link:**

```
function mapLink(myAddress) {
    return 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q='+escape(myAddress);
}
```

This works great on the iPhone.

Comment: In new versions of ios this needs to be a reference to maps.apple.com. something like: http://maps.apple.com/?q=cupertino

Comment: Which now redirects back to Google maps.

Answer (score 13):

A link to http://maps.google.com/maps will automatically open in the map application

You can set a destination address (daddr) and start address (saddr) in the link:

http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino

You can see some more options at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Comment: As per the latest version of the docs, this needs to be a link to http://maps.apple.com/

Answer (score 4):

If you use the standard link that would display a map in the browser, it will automatically open in Google Maps on the device.  That includes links that show directions.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like:

```
<a href='maps:daddr=<destination>&saddr=Current%20Location'>Directions</a>
```

where  may be a lat/lon pair (separated by a comma) or a place. Ensure you URI encode the destination to ensure it works.

Comment: can you show an example with an actual address? I am trying to do this but the map application always returns back with an error?