# Open google map taking the address from PHP variable

Tags: php, google-maps, web-applications, iphone-web-app

I have an address stored in a php variable (say `$add`). I am trying to create a link in my `Web App`, which when clicked will open the `Google Maps` App in the `iPhone` with the `$add` marked. I don't want to embed the map in the web app.

Can anyone give a few pointers how to go about it?

Comment: this looks like a good resource, http://stackoverflow.com/a/8946754/922168

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just link to `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?=$add?>` this should open the maps app on iPhone by default (and android incidentally)

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data over url parameters:

Check info here:

[Google Map Parameters](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters)