# Is it possible to code an address in a web page so that iOS and Android will recognize it and load their native map program?

Tags: android, ios, html

So I am building and HTML 5 app to run on mobile devices and I have addresses. I am wondering if it is possible to code them somehow to make iOS and Android recognize them as such and launch the native mapping app.

An example that I know works is phone numbers...I can code a link with "tel:" and a mobile phone will dial the number.

Is there something like this for addresses and maps?

Thanks!

David

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy tag you can use across platforms but I did find a few suggestions for iOS under this topic: [Link to iPhone map App from HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840769/link-to-iphone-map-app-from-html-page)

Perhaps there is something similar for Google Maps on Android?

Answer (score 0):

In android you can control WebView's behaviour when the user click on a link by setting a custom WebViewClient and override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method. In the example, if a user click on a link that ends with "toast" a toast will be showed. Of course you can do more fancy checks with regex and do something more sofisticated. I don't know how to achieve this on ios but I hope it can help.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith("toast")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**EDIT** 
It looks like it can be done on ios too, try to check [this](http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/iphone-development/how-to-override-uiwebview-links-request-action-with-your-own-custom-method/) example.

Comment: Is this just for native apps, or can it work in the default browser? My app is a web app, not native...

Comment: @David yes, I thought your app was html in a webview, for a mobile site I have no idea sorry :)